# Tag creation pluralization bug

Tags: bug, tags, plurals, tag-creation

On Ask Ubuntu, [here is what the tag creation dialog looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WNwl.png). I was trying to create a new tag (although the discussion of said new tag is irrelevant here), and I stumbled across a pluralization bug. I typed out the dialog, but if you prefer to see it as an image, I've linked it above.

> ### Are you sure you want to create new tags?
>
> The following tags do not exist: [windows-11].
>
> Did you intend to create these tags?
>
> Check your spelling and make sure existing tags do not already cover the topic.

The plurals are wrong. Here is what I think it should say instead (when creating one new tag):

> ### Are you sure you want to create this new tag?
>
> The following tag does not exist: [windows-11].
>
> Did you intend to create this tag?
>
> Check your spelling and make sure existing tags do not already cover the topic.

Comment: You'd want to keep the original wording if there are multiple new tags being added to the question. This fix would require the wording change when there is only one new tag, and keeping the existing if there are two or more.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, but in this instance, I'm only creating one new tag, and it is wrong